# Magento_Payment/translate not included in requirejs config for mixins

Tags: magento2.2, mixins

In a custom module, I am trying to implement a mixin for the `Magento_Payment/transparent` jQuery widget. My module is installed correctly (other parts are working fine), but the mixin isn't loading.

> **My_Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**
>
> ```
> var config = {
>     map: {
>         '*': {
>             my_custom_product: 'My_Module/js/my_custom_product'
>         }
>     },
>     config: {
>         mixins: {
>             'Magento_Payment/transparent': {
>                 'My_Module/js/checkout/payment/transparent-mixin': true
>             }
>         }
>     }
> };
> ```

When I get to the frontend checkout payment screen, I see that `Magento_Payment/transparent` is loading; however, it's not loading with my mixin. I looked in `pub/static/frontend/Package/theme/en_US/requirejs-config.js` to verify that my configuration is in fact included, and it is:

> **pub/static/frontend/Package/theme/en_US/requirejs-config.js**
>
> ```
> (function() {
> var config = {
>     map: {
>         '*': {
>             my_custom_product: 'My_Module/js/my_custom_product'
>         }
>     },
>     config: {
>         mixins: {
>             'Magento_Payment/transparent': {
>                 'My_Module/js/checkout/payment/transparent-mixin': true
>             }
>         }
>     }
> };
> require.config(config);
> })();
> ```

Now that I know the config should have my custom mixin included, I turned to debugging the `mage/requirejs/mixins.js` file. On line **126** I added a breakpoint and specifically waited for `Magento_Payment/transparent` to be the value of the `path` variable. When doing that `Magento_Payment/transparent` isn't listed in the configuration object, and thus my mixin doesn't get loaded.

[image: Chrome Dev Tools Scope at Breakpoint]

I know the way this is referenced is within the payment module's `iframe` template:

```
<form class="form" id="co-transparent-form" autocomplete="off" action="#" method="post" data-bind="mageInit: {
    'transparent':{
        'controller': getControllerName(),
        'gateway': getCode(),
        'orderSaveUrl':getPlaceOrderUrl(),
        'cgiUrl': getCgiUrl(),
        'dateDelim': getDateDelim(),
        'cardFieldsMap': getCardFieldsMap(),
        'nativeAction': getSaveOrderUrl(),
        'expireYearLength': getExpireYearLength()
    }, 'validation':[]}">
<!-- ko with: getCcFormView() -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
</form>
```

Is extending `Magento_Payment/transparent` possible, or do I need to find another way to add my custom functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to have been a cache issue. After fiddling with looking at the compiled `requirejs-config.js` file, I noticed the one the browser was using wasn't the same as the compiled version I was looking at. Clearing the browser cache resolved this issue for me.